# How do you git format-patch between head and commit head - x?

Tags: git

Sometimes I commit my changes and then suddenly remember that I forgot to add some comment or do some simple formatting, and having done that I do yet another commit. When it comes time to format a patch, I don't want that "small changes" commit to become a separate patch. I want to take the last two commits and merge them to one patch as if they were a diff between current state and before I started committing.

Googling the issue didn't help. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't pushed your changes, use interactive git rebase and mark those commits as fixup:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5

# opens editor with:
pick  deadbeaf commit
fixup abcd123  small change # edit this line to say "fixup", then save and exit editor
pick  3133715  another commit
```

Alternatively, if you discover you forgot some changes right after committing, add that change to the index and use `git commit --amend` to add it to your HEAD commit

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is probably to use interactive rebase to squash together those two commits.  If the incomplete commit was `A` and the subsequent small correction to that was commit `B`, giving the following commit graph:

```
 ---- A --- B (master)
```

You can do:

```
 git rebase -i A^
```

This will pop up a text editor with instructions on how to edit this file in order to reorder, remove, edit or squash together commits in the history.  (In this case, the history is just everything since the parent of `A`, which is only `A` and `B`.)

You can change `pick` to `squash` t the beginning of the line corresponding to commit `B`, save the file, exit the editor, and the history `master` will be rewritten so that they are a single commit.

Obviously, since this is rewriting history, you should avoid this if you've shared those commits with anyone already.

[This section of Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/ch6-4.html) has useful information about rewriting history in this way.

---

Alternatively, this is a simple enough situation that you could just do:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
git commit --amend
```

However, if the two commits aren't right at the tip of your branch, interactive rebase is a better approach.

Comment: reset + amend is obviously wrong. Either you amend the commit, or you do a soft reset and then commit by `git commit -C ORIG_HEAD`

Comment: @knittl: "obviously wrong" <-- no, the OP said that he already had two commits.